# If 'a' is constant, and this formula, x' = x × a, represents the equation of motion of a particle, why does it imply that |x| is constant?

Tags: calculus

I'm doing some work on kinematics and vector calculus. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why 'x' = x × a' holding true implies that |x| is constant. Note that 'a' is constant acceleration vector, and ' x' ' is the position vector differentiated.

Comment: Hint: You should be able to see that $x\cdot x' =0$

Comment: thank you, how did I miss that! differentiating |x| gives you (1/|x|)*(x.x')=0 => constant :)

Comment: Or simply differentiating $x\cdot x$ gives that $|x|^2$ is constant ...